# How to avoid making self and former employee look bad when reporting on fixing former employee's work?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, scrum, daily-standups

A former employee in good standing has changed jobs. Unfortunately a lot of their work just prior to leaving did not satisfy some acceptance criteria found by QA, and had other bugs.  I'm picking up the slack in fixing them. I expect some of it to not be trivial for me to begin fixing (due to my skill/knowledge being lower), and to have to work through this for a while, and what is the best way I should talk about this during daily stand ups?

My goals are

1. not to make it sound like I'm speaking badly about the code or the former employee that left, whose work I'm fixing.
2. to try not to make myself look bad as I'm going to be busy fixing something that didn't pass muster (I think it looks bad when you push things that are found to have issues when tested), for at least a single sprint, wherein I may not be contributing as much to the new work we've pulled in.

   - not to sound like I'm trying to deflect responsibility for fixing it, but certainly I wouldn't want to be mistaken for the source of these issues.

Edit: To clarify the tickets bounced our QA process as they didn't satisfy all the acceptance criteria within them and some other bugs were found, so perhaps saying they only had bugs isn't precise. (The code's already merged in behind a feature flag though.)

Comment: Do you have any idea why a lot of their code just before leaving was buggy?  "reasonable explanations" can help a lot here.  For example, if they were rushing to try to get finished on a big chunk of work before departure, then that would provide a fair amount of explanation.

Comment: @BenBarden rushing to finish before departure is a fair assumption, albeit I didn't keep that close an eye their progress

Comment: Were you assigned to fix the bugs/overall quality, or are you taking that on yourself? If you were assigned, presumably your manager (who is really the only person that matters) already knows where the bugs came from and why you are working on them.

Comment: @GreySage I've assumed I would be taking care of it as we have small teams.

Answer (score 133):

You are worrying about nothing. Software has bugs, that is inevitable, and everyone knows it. QA finds bugs, hopefully puts them into a bug tracking system, and you take one bug from the bug tracker, fix it, then the next one and so on until you are finished.

There is no need to mention where this bug comes from. Nobody cares. If someone asks you why there are so many bugs, you say “because QA is doing a good job”. If anyone actually complains, ask here again and tell us about their complaint.

Comment: How do you know that you're "finished"?

Comment: @Gherman you are finished when QA either doesn't find any bugs (rare), or when any bugs they find are not urgent/big enough to warrant fixing "now". Done usually means the software meets all requirements, and is functional enough to pass some level of quality testing (level of quality depends on target audience, type of software, etc).

Comment: >no need to mention where this bug comes from. Nobody cares.
The organization I work with cares about this more than anything else - why do bugs exist in the first place (lack of feature definition, lack of domain understanding, lack of exploratory testing etc.) Just felt it was worth mentioning that it's organization dependent - some organizations very much care where the bugs came from (sometimes more than what the bug itself was).

Comment: @Gherman When leave the job, or the product reaches end-of-life. But then you're starting all over again with the next.

Comment: @user2152081, this walks the fine line between trying to improve their process and simply looking for scapegoats. If you spend more time on determining the source of errors, then you are taking that time away from new feature development, which will help your Org. more. Trying to be perfect causes problems and is usually more detrimental than useful.

Comment: @user2152081 They care about that stuff even for active new-feature development?  That seems extreme, and possibly waterfall-y?

Comment: If there's an employee who creates lots of bugs, he may be degrading the development process, and that should be handled by management. But if the bugs are from an ex-employee, there's not much that can be done about them other than trying to fix them.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with this answer. If you every so often say "Yeah, thats diffucult because the code isnt optimal", they might start to think that that is the result of the current employees.

Comment: OP appears a bit concerned b/c s/he doesn't want others to think s/he is the person that originated the bugs. In that respect, I think a response that says _"Sorry, that code was already present when I started working on it and I'm still familiarizing myself with the code-base"_ would be a reasonable response that can help OP note that there's a subset of those bugs that weren't caused by OP.

Comment: @computercarguy The organization is suffering from pretty severe quality issues, undermining customer confidence. Agreed it's a balance, but fixing bugs doesn't meaningfully improve quality long term - the process has to be improved so the bugs don't exist in the first place. Buggy new features disappoint people even if the bugs are eventually fixed. So no, new features won't help the org more in this circumstance if those new features frustrate the users too much with their bugginess. I just meant to point out that this answer does not reflect my experience with large enterprise projects.

Comment: @DavidRice You're surprised it's interesting to an organization where new bugs are coming from? Put another way, if you solve one bug you fix a bug, if you address the root cause you potentially fix many bugs. Yes, organization (and myself) care about root cause for bugs introduced by new work. Actively analyzing issues and changing the process to avoid those issues sounds waterfall-y? Agile doesn't mean "ship bugs", there's a place in agile for rock solid MVPs that are limited in scope but not robustness.

Comment: @user2152081, so yes, there is a difference between "we're already 99% perfect, but we want to be 100%" and "we need to get this monster under control". If the Org. is trying to be perfectionist, my comment applies, but I've also worked at places with extremely buggy legacy code that had little to no previous QA, half completed features, and worse. Getting to the root cause of errors in that case is definitely useful, but can still waste precious time getting things fixed if the cause "needs" to be found before the bug is fixed.

Comment: @user2152081 I wouldn't ship bugs, but if I'm working on a new feature, I code it up, and the QA finds a bug in the new code, I fix it before it's demoed to the customer, or if it's a more fundamental flaw with the feature, we discuss it with the customer, but caring more about *why* there's a bug rather than *that* there's a bug seems odd to me.

Comment: @DavidRice definitely I was being a bit hyperbolic, there are very important bugs. We don't have that separation between dev and QA, we work hand-in-hand and generally QA is there for exploratory/regression testing more than feature verification. Minor bugs are never going away, but they usually point in the direction of e.g. lack of domain modeling, architectural complexity, etc. The current status quo is bugs found in new features are generally unanticipated interactions, once development is done there are "no bugs" in the relatively tiny scope that backs the effort. Dev does QA.

Comment: @DavidRice Understanding *why* a bug occurred is critical to reducing the overall rate of bugs generated by an organization.  It might be that most bugs are created because of incomplete or incorrect specifications.  Or maybe it is a poor quality codebase that is in sore need of refactoring.  Perhaps there is a developer on the team who is incompetent.  Once root causes are known, actions can be taken to reduce bug rates,  improve code quality, and reduce time to market for  new features.

Answer (score 32):

*In the stand up*, you should just state the facts:

> - Yesterday, I worked on bug #532 about the widgets being the wrong colour. Completed that and it's ready for the next deployment.
> - Today, I'm going to work on bug #536 about the crash when trying to order more widgets.
> - Potentially blocked because I don't understand the interactions with the back-end ordering service. Who can I talk to about that?

Anything else is out of scope for the stand up. Beyond that, someone (your team lead, your manager, whoever assigns you work) has asked you to work on these issues so they already know where they've come from and why you're not contributing new features to the sprint. Let them worry about that.

Comment: This is excellent, let the team/manager draw their own conclusions.  It doesn't reflect on you because you came into it after it was already 'coded', and have to ramp up.

Answer (score 18):

- > *1) Don't make it sound like I'm speaking badly about the code or the former employee that left, who's work I'm fixing.*

  Well, you talk about the problems in the code, without mentioning the why (or whom) part, bugs are there and they need to be fixed - that's it.
- > *2) Try not to make myself look bad as I'm going to be busy fixing something that didn't pass muster (I think it looks bad when you push things that are found to have issues when tested ), for at least a single sprint, wherein I may not be contributing as much to the new work we've pulled in.*

  Not your job to worry about the assignment. Once you're assigned something, only thing you should bother whether you're completing (or at least making progress) your assignments as expected or not. *Why* you are working on something, is almost always above your pay-grade.
- > *2.5) Not sound like I'm trying to deflect responsibility for fixing it, but certainly I wouldn't want to be mistaken for the source of these issues.*

  Why do you think this way? Code is written by someone else, QA check has been done by some other one, you're the one fixing it. No one will think you as the source of problem here.

So, finally, to answer:

> *what is the best way I should talk about this during daily stand ups?*

Just the same way if the bugs would have been found from someone else's code who's still working in the team. A bug is found, you're assigned to fix it, state the progress you made yesterday and state the plan for today; also mention if you need any help from the team to get over any obstacle you have. You're done.

Comment: I like this one, just talk about the code and the bugs, blame the code "I found it didn't do this" "I'm improving this..."

Comment: "Why do you think this way? Code is written by someone else, QA check has been done by some other one, you're the one fixing it. No one will think you as the source of problem here." If they're now responsible for feature X, and there are problems with feature X, then people could quite easily assume that they're the reason there are problems with feature X. They may not know, or remember, that somebody else was previously responsible for feature X, and they may not know *when* the issues were introduced to the code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Then, you need a better manager. I certainly don't want my manager to "forget" about it. Also note, this in context of a stand-up meeting, so the team (agile) is small (2~7, ideally) and cohesive.

Answer (score 4):

There are some underlying concepts of Scrum that are not being effectively honored in the situation you describe that are leading to the concern you have.

1) The whole team is meant to own the completion of work. A particular feature is only done once it is implemented, tested, and potentially releasable to the standard of the definition of done. You mention old work vs newly committed work, but this is committed work that the team has not finished. You are helping the team complete this work. This should definite not reflect badly on you nor should it be viewed as old work.

2) Development in Scrum is adaptive. Often times we need to refactor or "fix" things not because we screwed up before but because things have changed since then. This is normal.

3) We are human beings and perfect mastery of any skill is impossible. Scrum requires us to strive to be a team who can identify mistakes and improve how we work without it being a personal attack, not be a team that avoids those conversations. If you feel like saying that you are fixing a mistake someone made is considered bad, that's really a deep psychological safety challenge in the team that very much needs to be addressed.

Comment: I don't see any mention of Scrum specifically in the question.  However, the points you make should be applicable to any agile process. And #3 (don't shoot the messenger) is especially important to any organization / team / whatever that aspires to be something more than dysfunctional.

Comment: It wasn't. It was just inferred from the tags.

Answer (score 3):

Just report to the company bug tracker and your superior what is the current status of the code by telling the simple truth and without hiding anything.

When filling the bug tracker, try to avoid mentioning the former dev's name as much as possible and also avoid adjectives (bad, poor, shitty...). Just focus on facts.

Have a meeting with your superior and or the team explaining the situation and the needed resources to go through the whole fixing: maybe you need a few more weeks, maybe another dev is needed, maybe a training for you etc. Your superior knows you and your strengths so if a bug needs some knowledge you don't have, he shouldn't blame you.